# Как сделать чтоб цикл for выводил каждый i через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы информация выводилась не сразу а последовательно например через 500ms

```
const MAX_VALUE = 10;

console.log("Begin");

for (let i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
  console.dir({ i, date: new Date() });
}

console.log("The end");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и без асинхронного кода

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < 
milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: а можно применительно к задаче?

Comment: Сорян за форматирование потом поправлю.  const sleep =...; const MAX_VALUE = 10;

     console.log("Begin");

    for (let i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      sleep(500); console.dir({ i, date: new Date() });
    }

console.log("The end");

Comment: Пользователи будут благодарны зависшему приложению, где нельзя ничего делать пока работает вывод))

Comment: Ну если важна точность временного интервала то придётся потерпеть. setTimeout не гарантирует точность временного промежутка. Если на интервал пофиг, тогда тайм-аут и интервал правильнее будут.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MAX_VALUE = 10;



for (let i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.dir(i);
  }, (i + 1) *1000); 
}
```

Сразу предупреждаю, т.к. это асинхронная функция, то "The end" высветится гораздо раньше, чем исполнится весь код. Чтобы этого не было вам надо будет изучить тему Промисов (Promise) и async/await

Comment: "The end" можно на последней итерации выводить. Однако тему Промисов (Promise) и async/await изучить, конечно, не повредит.

Comment: @PavelNazarian можно на последней итерации, да, но смысла нет я считаю